# Requesting an HTTPS URL with pear http_request fails. Why?

Tags: https

I am using Ubuntu with OpenSSL installed. When I request a normal URL with pear, it works fine, but when I request an https url, it doesn't work. Why?

Comment: You are ubuntu? Interesting.

Comment: Check the error code.